# Complex SQL Query with Business Logic

Tags: sql, join, mysql-logic

I'm stuck with a complex query where I need to implement some business logic. Below are the tables that I'm having (I have omitted extra columns for readabality)

```
Team - TeamID, TeamName
TeamMember - MemberID, TeamID, MemberName
Question - QuestionID, CategoryID, DifficultyLevelID, Question
Category - CategoryID, CategoryName
DifficultyLevel - DifficultyLevelID, DifficultyLevelName
QuestionOffered - QuestionOfferedID, QuestionID, OfferedTo
```

Now, The business logic is, I have 10 categories (like Science, History, Geography etc.) and 3 Difficulty level (i.e. Easy, Medium, Hard). Each category and difficulty level have 5 questions.

So 3  x 5 = 15 questions for each category (5 Easy, 5 Medium, 5 Hard). Total 15 x 10 (categories) = 150 questions.

Now I want that everytime a user comes in, I'll check whether I have already offered (can be tracked from QuestionsOffered table) all the 5 questions under that category and difficulty level, if so, then I won't show that category and difficulty level again.

So, say I come in first time I'll get all the category and then selecting a category I'll get all the difficulty level. Now I select Easy and proceed. So under each category I can select a particular difficulty level 5 times after that I'll get the category and other difficulty levels (i.e. Medium and Hard) after I have done with all 5 easy.

So, in this way, if I'm done with all 5 easy, 5 medium and 5 hard questions under a same category, the category itself won't show up.

Ofcourse I can implement this logic in programming for populating the category but that would end up with numerous lines of code.

So is there any way to check this business logic in SQL? So that I will get the data to populate?

Answer (score 0):

inner join your questions, categories, and levels together, then left join to the questions already offered. Filter where any field in the questions offered table is null, and you will have a list of unanswered questions? perhaps?

Comment: Well, I missed one thing, that the quiz I'm implementing is a team based. So say any member from my team depletes a category or a difficulty level, so any other team member won't get that category or level.

@Jeremy, What you have said is not much clear to me. Because, when I want to populate a category I'd like to check whether I have 15 rows for that category (form questions offered table) for that team. If not, that means the team have not depleted the whole category, so I'll populate it.

Comment: Next when the member selects a category, for populating level, I'll check whether I have 5 rows for each level for that team, if not then I can populate it.

Hope that makes sense. But my question is how can I achieve this using query?